# Is it OK to save a reference to the object managed by a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Here's a working version of what I'm doing.

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct thing {
    int blah;
};

struct parentObj {
    parentObj(thing & incomingThing) : isThisOK(incomingThing) {};
    thing & isThisOK;
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<thing> thingInstance = make_shared<thing>();
    shared_ptr<parentObj> theObj = make_shared<parentObj>(*thingInstance);
}
```

I like assigning a shared pointer to a reference of it's type. (ctrl+f isThisOK)

Are there unintended consequences here? Should I be using a weak pointer?

Comment: It's just as okay as saving a reference to any other object.  Meaning, the compiler won't catch object lifetime errors for you, that burden is on your shoulders.

Comment: It compiles, but I'm not sure this is the best use of `shared_ptr`. `parentObj` reference to `thing&` does not allow it to know when accessing it is valid. You might as well not use `shared_ptr` at all.

Comment: The one big problem is that once `theObj` has zero references, it destroys its underlying object that `thingInstance` will still point to even though it no longer exists.

Comment: @sanitizedUser wrong, default destruction does not destroy reference data members.

Comment: This code is OK, but I suppose your actual code is more complicated - you will have to give guarantee that once thingInstance is destroyed, then the Obj will not use its reference (otherwise you get UB). You may pass std::weak_ptr to parentObj to protect against UB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is just as okay as this:

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct thing {
    int blah;
};

struct parentObj {
    parentObj(thing& incomingThing) : isThisOK(incomingThing) {};
    thing& isThisOK;
};

int main()
{
    thing thingInstance;
    shared_ptr<parentObj> theObj = make_shared<parentObj>(thingInstance);
}
```

Just like function parameter should, by default, be agnostic of the ownership strategy unless needed, I would say that what you're doing is right, and even recommend it given a particular case. If your object is agnostic of the ownership strategy unless needed, this is usually the way to go.

Just be aware of two things:

1. You'll have to be careful with your lifetime and set a boundary when a `parentObj` should be considered invalid.
2. Be aware that this is much easier to do something like your code when you use `std::unique_ptr` instead, since the owner of a unique pointer is much easier to track. When reading a code with unique pointers, you can easily spot where the lifetime should end and where it is transferred. With a shared one, not so clear. With a unique pointer, you can set the boundary "statically", let's say, a `parentObj` is invalid after the `thing` died, and it should be clear when the lifetime of both has ended. If you have a shared pointer, I would recommend you have a way to check the validity at runtime before using the `parentObj`.

I would use a `std::weak_ptr` only if by design `parentObj` should check the validity of `thing` at runtime, and users of `parentObj` cannot check the validity of `thing`. Usually, there is a place in the code that you can be sure when `thing` and `parentObj` start and end their lifetime. If you have a place where you know their lifetime, then I would say that it's the responsibility of that code to check the validity of `thing` and `parentObj` and let those two type be simpler.